# How to use the UniqueName in Row Level dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I Need UniqueName in row level dimension instead of column level.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CurrMemID] AS [Product].[Product Line].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[CurrMemID]} ON COLUMNS,
      {[Product].[Product Line].Members} ON ROWS 
FROM  [Adventure Works]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVtkn.png)

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? And provide an expected ouput? Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @mxix, can u please click on 'enter image description here' ,

Comment: @mxix, i need CurrentMember.UniqueName in Row level instead of column level

Comment: uhmm reverse your ON COLUMS with ON ROWS and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling what you might be asking for is not possible: as soon as you swap rows and column analysis services will expand the cellset out to several columns - one for each product.

If your aim is to have two parallel columns - the *first* with the uniqueName and the *second* with the caption, then you could do something like this and then in the client just ignore the first column:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrMemID] AS 
  [Product].[Product Line].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrMemCaption] AS 
  [Product].[Product Line].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
      {
        [Measures].[CurrMemID],
        [Measures].[CurrMemCaption]
      } ON 0,
      {[Product].[Product Line].Members} ON 1
FROM  [Adventure Works];
```